# regular expression add double quotes around values and keys in bash

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

i need a valid JSON format to request ES.
i have a string like

```
{ 
time:  { 
          from:now-60d,
          mode:quick,
          to:now } 
}
```

should be something like

```
 { 
time:  { 
          "from":"now-60d",
          "mode":"quick",
          "to":"now" } 
}
```

so my question, there is any solution to add double quotes around keys and values of my string in bash ??

thanks

Comment: Beware of [XY problems](http://xyproblem.info/). How did you get the data in this format in the first place? Rather than fixing it after the fact, can you fix the source?

Comment: It really would be much better to get the source to generate correct data in the first place. It is bad design to write software that "patches" the output of a preceding layer just to get it working.

Comment: Source was removing double quotes, Thats a good point. I should escape double quotes in the source. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd want to produce proper JSON from the start, or at least write a proper parse for what you have. But it you just need to do this once, it might be faster to use the following and fix up any problems manually:

```
$ echo "{ 
time:  { 
      from:now-60d,
      mode:quick,
      to:now } 
}" | perl -p -e 's/(\w+):([^{, ]+)/"$1":"$2"/'
{ 
time:  { 
      "from":"now-60d",
      "mode":"quick",
      "to":"now" } 
}
```

Comment: You would also need to quote `time`

Comment: This will work with the specific data shown in the question but it scales very badly. I suspect you have added stuff to the character class until you got the right result.

Comment: @Borodin "Scale" is the wrong word. This has nothing to do with scale. It's _fragile_, bit I said it's not production code. It's not true that every program in the world needs to be industrial strength to be useful.

Comment: `perl -pe's/([\w\-]+)/"$1"/g'` will handle `time` as well. `perl -pe's/(?:^|[{,])\s*\K([\w\-](?:\s+[\w\-]*))(?=\s+(?:[,}]|$)/"$1"/gm'` should be more robust and more easily extensible

Comment: (There's a missing paren at the end of my last pattern.)